# Разъезжается navbar при масштабировании

Tags: bootstrap

[image: NAVBAR в масштабе 150%]
В Chrome при масштабировании `NAVBAR` (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) меняется несколько раз:

- при масштабе в 100% - это одна строка
- при масштабе в 150% - уже две строки (фото выше)
- при масштабе в 200% - опять одна строка, элементы меню скрыты списком.

Отсюда вопрос, как исключить второе состояние, когда образуется две (или более) строки с элементами навигации, т.е. как сделать так, чтобы `navbar` всегда был в одну строку - либо раскрыт, либо собран в список?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уменьшить количество пунктов меню (уменьшить отступы, сами пункты), или скрыть некоторые элементы при уменьшении экрана, или настроить переменную `@grid-float-breakpoint` (по умолчанию,по-моему, 768px) или перенести сворачивание в другой медиа-запрос. В [документации](http://bootstrap-3.ru/components.php#navbar) все расписано.